# 3D graph with live updating

Tags: java, python, graph, 3d, matplotlib

So I have been doing hours and hours of research, and I cannot find anything efficient in python for what I need. Some things I found in Java and C work, but the data I need to graph is held in a `pandas DataFrame` and it would be much better if I could get this graphing to work in python.

I have looked into Matplotlibs 3D graphing using color as the 3rd axis, but I feel as though that would not be the best way to do it because I need live updating.

My data is for accelerometry phone data for every second over a span of 2 months and I would like to be able to have a point that is updated to show the change in accelerometry and such. Here is a quick video of what I need, but using java: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=vblcfZ291vw

So is there a good way to do this in python?

**DataFrame example:**

```
     x.mean    y.mean    z.mean                 time
0 -1.982905  3.395062  8.558263  2012-01-18 14:00:03
1  0.025276 -0.399172  7.404849  2012-01-18 14:00:04
2 -0.156906 -8.875595  1.925565  2012-01-18 14:00:05
3  2.643088 -8.307801  2.382624  2012-01-18 14:00:06
4  3.562265 -7.875230  2.312898  2012-01-18 14:00:07
5  4.441432 -7.907592  2.851774  2012-01-18 14:00:08
6  4.124187 -7.854146  2.727229  2012-01-18 14:00:09
7  4.199698 -8.135596  2.677706  2012-01-18 14:00:10
8  4.407856 -8.133449  2.214902  2012-01-18 14:00:11
9  4.096238 -8.453822  1.359692  2012-01-18 14:00:12
```

Comment: What does the dataframe look like, can you give us na sample of the data?

Comment: I'll add a quick example

Answer (score 1):

Enthought's Mayavi 3D plotting package in python might work for what you need. It uses VTK.
http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi/

Using the traits utility you can interactively update the data in the plot the following two pages from the documents discuss this

http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/building_applications.html#making-the-visualization-live
http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab_animating.html#mlab-animating-data

Comment: That looks interesting, but can it do the live update that I need with accelerometry? I can't really tell from the tutorials and documentation info

Comment: Enthought roles their own python distribution. They have a very active mailing list. If you address your  installation issues to that list you'll a quick answer for your particular configuration